# Unable to click <a> tag inside a table cell and switchTo it using Selenium Webdriver JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to **get specific values** from the general site that contains the annual reports of public-listed firms using `Selenium Webdriver JS`. Kindly help me investigate. I get the `issue` on clicking the `Annual Report` link.

The process that I'm trying to automate is listed below:

- Go to site (http://edge.pse.com.ph/financialReports/form.do)
- Filter by type of report (`sendKeys('Annual Report'`) and `fromDate` attribute value to `4-23-2012` (year 2012 to get 4-5 annual reports of each firm)
- click `btnSearch`
- click `Annual Report` link per company row to view report (`a` tag is inside a `td`)
- switch to the popup window
- get specific values as `object` values and store it in the `array`
- close popup window and get back to `initial` window
- Repeat it on the `succeeding` company rows (take note that the site has `pagination` and a `total` of `22` pages (or tables) must be looped through

Kindly check my initial code for the process below. I also think that my `implicitWaits` are working. Does it apply on Selenium `executeScript` commands?

```
  var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();

    driver.get('http://edge.pse.com.ph/financialReports/form.do');

    driver.wait(until.titleIs('Financial Reports'), 1000)

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.name('tmplNm')).sendKeys('Annual Report');

    driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('fromDate').setAttribute('value', '4-23-2012')");

    driver.findElement(By.id('btnSearch')).click();

    var totalPages = 22;
    var num = 0;

    while (num < totalPages) {

        var pagingArray = driver.executeScript("document.querySelector('.paging').getElementsByTagName('span')");

        for (var p = 0; p < pagingArray.length; p++) {

            var page = driver.executeScript("pagingArray[p].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]");
            page.click();

            var table = driver.executeScript("document.querySelector('table.list')");

            for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {

                for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {

                    if (j == 1) {
                        // Store the current window handle
                        var winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

                        var reportLink = driver.executeScript("table.rows[i].cells[j].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]");
                        reportLink.click();

                        // Switch to new window opened
                        for (var winHandle in driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                        }

                        var companyName = driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('companyName').innerHTML");
                        var stockTicker = driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('companyStockSymbol').innerHTML");

                        checkCompany(companyName, stockTicker);

                        var tableBS = driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('BS')");

                        var currentYear = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[1].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");

                        if (!checkBalanceSheets(companyName, currentYear)) {

                            bsCurrentYear = new Object();
                            bsCurrentYear.year = currentYear;
                            bsCurrentYear.currentAssets = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[2].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            bsCurrentYear.totalAssets = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[3].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            bsCurrentYear.currentLiabilities = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[4].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            bsCurrentYear.totalLiabilities = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[5].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            bsCurrentYear.company = companyName;
                            balanceSheets.push(bsCurrentYear);
                        }

                        var previousYear = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[1].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");

                        if (!checkBalanceSheets(companyName, previousYear)) {

                            bsPreviousYear = new Object();
                            bsPreviousYear.year = previousYear;
                            bsPreviousYear.currentAssets = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[2].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            bsPreviousYear.totalAssets = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[3].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            bsPreviousYear.currentLiabilities = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[4].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            bsPreviousYear.totalLiabilities = driver.executeScript("tableBS.rows[5].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            bsPreviousYear.company = companyName;
                            balanceSheets.push(bsPreviousYear);
                        }

                        var tableIS = driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('IS')");

                        if (!checkIncomeStatements(companyName, currentYear)) {
                            isCurrentYear = new Object();
                            isCurrentYear.year = currentYear;
                            isCurrentYear.grossrevenue = driver.executeScript("tableIS.rows[4].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            isCurrentYear.grossexpense = driver.executeScript("tableIS.rows[7].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            isCurrentYear.netincomeaftertax = driver.executeScript("tableIS.rows[10].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            isCurrentYear.company = companyName;
                            isCurrentYear.eps = driver.executeScript("tableIS.rows[12].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            incomeStatements.push(isCurrentYear);
                        }

                        if (!checkIncomeStatements(companyName, previousYear)) {
                            isPreviousYear = new Object();
                            isPreviousYear = previousYear;
                            isPreviousYear.grossrevenue = driver.executeScript("tableIS.rows[4].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            isPreviousYear.grossexpense = driver.executeScript("tableIS.rows[7].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            isPreviousYear.netincomeaftertax = driver.executeScript("tableIS.rows[10].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            isPreviousYear.company = companyName;
                            isPreviousYear.eps = driver.executeScript("tableIS.rows[12].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]");
                            incomeStatements.push(isPreviousYear);
                        }
                        // Close the new window, if that window no more required
                        driver.close();

                        // Switch back to original browser (first window)
                        driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        driver.executeScript("document.querySelector('.paging').getElementsByTagName('a')[2].click()");
        num++;
    }
```

**PS** `CheckBalanceSheets` and `CheckIncomeStatements` are for validating **IF** the `year` already exists and has been recorded before for the respective company

```
function checkCompany(name, ticker) {
    var found = companies.some(function(el) {
        return el.name === name;
    });

    if (!found) { companies.push({ name: name, ticker: ticker }); }
}

function checkBalanceSheets(name, year) {

    var found = balanceSheets.some(function(el) {
        return el.name === name && el.year === year;
    });

}

function checkIncomeStatements(name, year) {

    var found = incomeStatements.some(function(el) {
        return el.name === name && el.year === year;
    });

}
```